# replacing a character in a list even when it appears more than once

Tags: python, list, replace

I'm doing the infamous Hangman game for Python. Here's my code:

```
import random
import string
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"
def load_words():
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    line = inFile.readline()
    wordlist = string.split(line)
    return wordlist
def choose_word(wordlist):
    return random.choice(wordlist)
wordlist = load_words()
word=list(choose_word(wordlist))          #I read that it's preferable to
print "Welcome to the game, Hangman!"     #use lists as string are more
print "I am thinking of a word that is", len(word), "letters long." #tricky
def check(word):                           #because they are immutable and 
    guesses=20                            #some problems might arise
    let="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    altword=list(len(word)*"-")
    while "-" in altword and guesses>0:
        print "You have", guesses, "guesses left."
        print "Available letters: ", let
        letter=raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
        newlet=let.replace(letter, "")
        let=newlet
        if letter in word:
            index=word.index(letter)          #here is the problem when a
            altword[index]=letter             #letter appears more than once
            print "Good guess: ", ''.join(map(str, altword))
        else:
            guesses=guesses-1
            print "Oops! That letter is not in my word: ", ''.join(map(str, altword))
    if guesses<=0:
        print "Sorry, you've been hanged! The word is: ", ''.join(map(str, word))
    else:
        print "Congratulations, you won!"
check(word)
```

How can I replace the `"-"` in the altword *if* the letter appears more than once? I tried to word it in other ways, but the problem is that said letter may or may *not* appear multiple times in any given word, and I need to first check somehow for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to count the number of occurrences, for the game logic it's just important if the guessed letter is correct (in the word) or incorrect (not in the word).

To replace all matches you could use a simple `for`-loop with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
if letter in word:
    for idx, char in enumerate(word):  # go through the word (remembering the index)
        if char == letter:             # check if it is a match
            altword[idx] = letter      # replace the character at idx in "altword" with "letter"
    print "Good guess: ", ''.join(map(str, altword))
else:
    guesses -= 1
    print "Oops! That letter is not in my word: ", ''.join(map(str, altword))
```

Comment: `if letter in word:` will give true even if the letter occurs once, I think the requirement was for multiple times

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee The question asks for letters that *may* occur multiple times. In the context of hangman it's not really important how often the letter is present in `word`, just if it is (good) or if it isn't (bad). The `for`-loop with `enumerate` works without knowing the exact number of matches. It just checks all elements.

Comment: yes, that what I'm saying **multiple times**
and `if letter in word:` will give `True` even if it appear once

Comment: _In the context of hangman it's not really important how often the letter is present in word_, I don't know the game so can't tell more but the question asked seemed to be asking if multiple occurrences are there or not

Comment: [Hangman (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)). In case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can check like this

```
'apple'.count('p')
```

this will give you the occurrence of p in apple
or you can use the same to detect words in a sentences

```
"apple are red and bananas are yellow and oranges are orange".count("and")
```

Comment: But this just gives the **count**. The question asks for the **indices** of the matches.

Comment: answered according to this line asked
**_but the problem is that said letter may or may not appear multiple times in any given word, and I need to first check somehow for that_**

Comment: Thank you, will try to remember this!